# SFML font segmentation faults

Tags: c++, fonts, segmentation-fault, sfml

I have read this: [Segfault when drawing text with SFML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428432/segfault-when-drawing-text-with-sfml)

I'm trying to implement a developer console into my project. Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
Class Console
{
    public:
      Console();
      void DisplayConsole();
      ...
    private:
      sf::Font m_consoleFont;
      sf::Text m_consoleText;
};

Console::Console()
{
    m_consoleFont.loadFromFile("font.ttf");
    ...
}

void Console::DisplayConsole()
{
    m_consoleText.setFont(m_consoleFont);
    m_consoleText.setString("Welcome!");
    ...
    ...draw(m_consoleText);
}
```

What am I not doing that the answer in that post said to do? I'm still getting crashes when I draw the text. I can draw the console background no problem. Can I also get an explanation on why it crashes, so I understand for the future?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I find that with Eclipse whenever I add a new resource (like a font) I need to do a clean build, otherwise I may end up with a crash/seg fault.  It looks to me like you're doing the right thing, as the font isn't destroyed before use.

Comment: I don't know if it's pertinent, but DisplayConsole() is run in the main program loop in another file. Could this help cause the problem?

Comment: For complete compatibility, window calls need to be made in the GUI thread (main thread).  You aren't doing anything wrong as long as DisplayConsole() isn't being calling in some other thread.  How does DisplayConsole() get access to the window that it is drawing to?

Comment: DisplayConsole() is actually DisplayConsole(sf::RenderWindow *window). In main.cpp, a new console object is called with m_console = new Console();. The function is later called with m_console->DisplayConsole(m_window) (m_window being a new sf::RenderWindow object.)

Comment: You might want to check if your call to loadFromFile() is succeeding, i.e. it returns true. If not, then your issue is there.